# Why is WAMP\XAMPP server(Windows 8) localhost working only on Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, browser, xampp, wamp

1.Changed `Listen 80` to `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` in httpd.conf

2.Commented `::1 localhost` in hosts

3.Tried changing default browser to Chrome

Comment: Are you using `WampServer` or `XAMPP`? They are not the same thing!

Comment: I've tried with both,but I prefer Wamp

Answer (score 1):

Good I like WAMPServer also.

*So this answer works only for WAMPServer!*

So, I assume you mean you want Chrome to be launched when you use the Wampmanager menus to get to for example `localhost` and `phpmyadmin`.
Wamp does not look for the systems default browser. It asks you what browser you want to use when you install it. If you want to change your answer after you have installed you need to do this.

I will assume you have WAMPServer instaled on the C: drive. If not then change C: appropriatly

```
Stop WAMPServer.
    i.e. on the wampmanager icon in the system tray [ Right Click -> Exit ]

Edit this file `c:\wamp\wampmanager.conf`

Change this parameter so it references where you have installed Chrome.
It is within the [main] section on roughly line 7

    navigator = "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Save the file.

Start WAMPServer again.
```

When you start WAMPServer it will check the wampmanager.conf file and from then on it should use your desired browser.